# Restarting the previous activity by pressing back button

Tags: java, android

I'm making an app in which there is a 'MainActivity.class' which has a button 'Edit profile' that leads to another activity, called 'Editprofile.class'. It (MainActivity) also has a TextView which displays a string (name).

Editprofile.class accepts a string from user and upon pressing a button 'add', the new String gets updated to the database, replacing the previous string. Now when, after updating, the user goes back to the MainActivity via the back button I want the TextView to display the new updated String; for which I have to restart MainActivity.

I have achieved this by using finish() function when the user presses the 'Edit profile' button and when the user presses the back button during the Editprofile activity, the MainActivity gets restarted via onBackPress() method.

Code for intent to start 'Editprofile.class':

> ```
> public void edit_profile(View view)  {                                                
>     Intent intent = new Intent(this, Editprofile.class)
>     startActivity(intent)  
>     finish();
>   }
> ```

Code to go back to 'MainActivity':

> ```
> @Override
> public void onBackPressed() {
>     finish();
>     startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
> }
> ```

I have managed to get the result I wanted but I would appreciate it if someone can tell me if it is the most efficient method.

*Should have I posted this in a Q/A format??*

Comment: From my experience, you don't need to write any code to make the Back button go back to the previous activity. This is the default behavior.

Comment: @Code-Guru yes, I'm aware of that. But I also wanted to 'refresh' the MainActivity so that the newly updated name will be displayed on going back; otherwise the previous name would still be displayed while the database would get updated.

Comment: Where does the "newly updated name" come from? From what I understand, the preferred solution to updating an Activity when it is restarted is to use the `onResume()` callback rather than killing the Activity and trying to create a new one.

Comment: In fact, I strongly suggest that you study about the Activity life-cycle. I think this will help you solve your problem in a way that plays safely with the underlying platform.

Comment: @Code-Guru You are correct. I should have used onResume(). Thank you!
"newly updated name" comes from the SQLite database I have created previously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative to @Mattias answer is to start `Editprofile` using  `startActivityForResult(...)`. That activity can then return a result indicating whether the user has actually edited his/her profile, which you'll be able to capture in `onActivityResult(...)` of `MainActivity`. Only if the profile changed the `TextView` needs to be updated.

It may take a few lines of extra coding, but is slightly more efficient than updating every single time `onResume()` gets hit. In my opinion it also a bit cleaner, although in terms of performance it probably won't be a big deal.

For an example, have a look at the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities) on the Android developers website.

Comment: +1 This is definitely a better solution than my suggestion to use `onResume()`.

Answer (score 3):

> But I also wanted to 'refresh' the MainActivity so that the newly updated name will be displayed on going back;

There's the `onResume()` method for just this sort of thing.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend using `startActivityForResult()` and updating your `MainActivity` in `onActivityResult()`.

(There is no need to check for an update in `onResume()`, since this method is called by *many* other instances than just returning from `Editprofile`.)

Answer (score 2):

Just:

- remove the `finish()` call in `edit_profile()`
- remove the entire `onBackPressed()` method

As you don't need to restart the activity (now it will be resumed which is: faster, better, easier and as intended). Update the TextView in `onResume()` instead of `onCreate()`.

Comment: Removing `finish()` from `edit_profile()` means that the OP can remove `onBackPressed()` completely.

Comment: Thank you! I knew I was doing something wrong by using so many finishes.

Answer (score 1):

Don't Use/override onBackPressed() anywhere in your program

just add the following method in the parent activity such as `MainActivity` and `EditProfile`

### In MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Start Activity on your onClick method using

```
    startActivityForResult(intentName, 0);
```

### In EditProfile.java

you use/override onStop() method

```
    @Override
protected void onStop()
{
    super.onStop();

}
```